# IVR Call through Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am working with project using asp.net(c#) & authorize.net's AIM & CIM methods  to process payment. Now I want to know that, Is there any authorize.net service or any other service which will directly call credit card issuing bank which will validating & verifying user in real time by asking some questions and then return with response.
By using this response we can able to take further decision for transaction processing.

Please kindly assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I know there is nothing like IVR call in a payment process, instead
if you want to do a Cardholder Authentication use **3-D Secure** (Three-Domain Secure)

Authorize.Net does not directly provide these services, but you integrate services provided by the **Visa** and **MasterCard** such as

> **Verified by VISA** / **MasterCard SecureCode**

For these you need to enroll in these program separately as a merchant.
And later you can enable these services into your Authorize.net account.

For more details visit :

[Authorize.Net - Cardholder Authentication Support Page](https://www.authorize.net/support/CNP/helpfiles/Account/Settings/Security_Settings/Fraud_Settings/Cardholder_Authentication.htm)

[Verified by VISA](https://usa.visa.com/run-your-business/small-business-tools/payment-technology/verified-by-visa.html)